# Auto increment keyword in sql 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to know what keyword v should use for autoincrement in the table with primary key in sql 2005

Comment: Now that I told you, click on the check mark.

Comment: @Hogan: Some people sale their souls for points!

Comment: @Jose Chama: We've established what Hogan is, it's just a matter of haggling on the price =)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Have a heart, I just wanna get to 3k so I can vote to close or reopen questions!  (How much do you charge?)

Comment: @Hogan: If you have to ask, you can't afford ;)

Answer (score 10):

Identity

```
 CREATE TABLE blah(
     [ID] int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
 )
```

Comment: +1, **IDENTITY (100,5)** to start at 100 and increment by 5, but I bet that is the default

Comment: Default is seed = 1, increment = 1 ... so equivalent to above is [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) - though the PRIMARY KEY part is certainly not a required part of the syntax... you may just as easily want your PK on a column other than the IDENTITY column (as with many things, it depends).

Comment: @Aaron: Primary key need was part of the question :D